# How to create group variable for a regression problem

Tags: multiple-regression

I have a small dataset with 800 observations. In this dataset there are some variables (i.e. `age`, `annual income`) composed of several different entries. Due to that, I would like to create groups for a regression problem. After that, I will perform a multilinear regression and also a random forest regression

The question is simply: How can I create the groups?

I do not want to create the groups in any arbitrary way but I do not know which should be the correct approach

Comment: If you are using R then `disc.Topdown` in the discretization package provides 3 methods each of which does not require tuning parameters.

Comment: Why do you need groups? Why can't you use the variables as they are?

Comment: For example, the variable `age`. It has more than 70 different ages recorded in the dataset. I though about grouping data ages in a group to analyse and to perform prediction. Why do you think it would not be a good idea?